# Mark a hive table as replicated/small

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible to tell `hive` that a certain table is "small", i.e., that it should be replicated to all nodes and operated upon in RAM?

Comment: What does it mean "operated upon in RAM"? map-join usage?

Comment: @dimamah: loaded into RAM as a hash table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following hint:

```
/*+ MAPJOIN(small_table) */
```

**UPDATE** BTW there are also other options such as **sort-merge-bucket** join  . But they require changes to the input tables to be bucketed on the same columns.

Here is some info on limitations / abilities of Map Joins from the Hortonworks docs

[HortonWorks docs on Mapside join optimizations](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/ds_Hive/optimize-joins.html#JoinOptimization-StarJoinOptimization)

An excerpt about the mapjoins is here for convenience

```
MAPJOINs are processed by loading the smaller table into an in-memory hash map and matching keys with the larger table as they are streamed through.

Local work:
read records via standard table scan (includes filters and projections) from source on local machine
build hashtable in memory
write hashtable to local disk
upload hashtable to dfs
add hashtable to distributed cache
Map task
read hashtable from local disk (distributed cache) into memory
match records? keys against hashtable
combine matches and write to output
No reduce task
Limitations of Current Implementation

The current MAPJOIN implementation has the following limitations:

The mapjoin operator can only handle one key at a time; that is, it can perform a multi-table join, but only if all the tables are joined on the same key. (Typical star schema joins do not fall into this category.)
Hints are cumbersome for users to apply correctly and auto conversion doesn't have enough logic to consistently predict if a MAPJOIN will fit into memory or not.
A chain of MAPJOINs is not coalesced into a single map-only job, unless the query is written as a cascading sequence of mapjoin(table, subquery(mapjoin(table, subquery....). Auto conversion will never produce a single map-only job.
The hashtable for the mapjoin operator has to be generated for each run of the query, which involves downloading all the data to the Hive client machine as well as uploading the generated hashtable files.
```